# Jq: How to move the child members to parent?

Tags: json, parent-child, jq

Consider the following json:

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1,
      d: 2
    }
  }
}
```

How can I move all the properties of b to be under the parent a:

```
{
  a: {
    c: 1,
    d: 2,
    b: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: `< in jq '. + { "a": (.a + .a.b) }'` is the best I can do, doesn't scale very well though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular case, you could do this:

```
$ jq '.a |= (.b = {}) + .b' input.json
```

Here we're updating object `a` with the original contents with `b` replaced with an empty object and combining it with the contents of the original `b`.

If that was too hard to reason about, this might be easier to follow:

```
$ jq '.a |=
    with_entries(if .key == "b"
        then (.value = {}), (.value | to_entries[])
        else .
    end)' input.json
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for nudging me in the right direction. A more general solution would be to use walk, which I've posted as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a variant of @Jeff-Mercado's first solution, but may be slightly easier to follow (notably because there is only one reference to .b, and because the grouping on the RHS is explicit):

```
 .a |= ({b:{}} + .b)
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this recursively for any field use:

```
walk
(
    if (type == "object" and has("b")) then
        .|=.b
    else
        .
    end
)
```