# How to move element to (new) child?

Tags: json, object, transformation, jq

Consider this document:

```
{"x": [
    {
        "a": {
            "b": [],
            "c": 42
        }
    },
    {
        "a": {
            "d": true
        }
    }
]}
```

But now I need to move all `b`s (that need not exist!) one level down like this:

```
{"x": [
    {
        "a": {
            "e": {
                "b": []
            },
            "c": 42
        }
    },
    {
        "a": {
            "d": true
        }
    }
]}
```

I've seen [the example that does the opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214984/jq-how-to-move-the-child-members-to-parent) but I haven't been able to apply that to my case unfortunately.

Comment: the input document is invalid JSON, update your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is valid JSON, and that it is acceptable to apply the transformation wherever it is possible, I’d use `walk`, for simplicity:

```
walk( if type == "object" and has("b")
      then .e = .b | del(.b)
      else . end )
```

You might want to check for the existence of .e as well to avoid clobbering it.

If your jq does not have `walk` then simply insert its def before the above; for the definition, simply google for: jq “def walk”